# Getting text from a url and displaying it (Almost works)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to get text from urls and display them as strings. Urls end with .txt as in www.gains.com/more.txt These text are long and they have a maximum size of 1MB. I am trying to  it with `AsyncTask`. The problem is that the code sometimes works. It worked the first time I ran the code the second time it didn't display the text. Sometimes the app would display the text sometimes it wouldn't. What is going on here? Here is my code.

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        // username, password, message, mobile
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            // constants
            int timeoutSocket = 5000;
            int timeoutConnection = 5000;

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url[0]);

            try {
                HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(httpget);
                final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    Log.w("MyApp", "Download Error: " + statusCode + "| for URL: " + url);
                    return null;
                }

                String line = "";
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

                HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResponseEntity.getContent()));  

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }

                line = total.toString();
                story.add(line); //story is my array i use to display the text
                return line;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("MyApp", "Download Exception : " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //This is empty i dont know what it does
        }
        }
```

Here is how i call it

```
new RequestTask().execute("www.gains.com/more.txt");
```

Also another smaller problem im having is that when the text is displayed I lose the format of the text as in i lose the spaces between paragraphs an get one huge paragraph. Is there a way to solve this? Should I use another method?

Answer (score 0):

Http request don't always take the same exact time. Have you tried increasing the timeout? 5000 mil seconds is not a lot, especially if your files reach 1MB in size.

Comment: I increased it to 100 times more. Still I dont get the text.

Answer (score 0):

Call the display function that will display the text from the file saved after the file is downloaded.

Use onPostExecute

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //You add the code where you call the text from the file saved
    }
```

You can call a function from the main activity that calls the thread.

This way, the view will only be displayed until the process of downloading and saving your text is finished.

Edit: Here's a sample

```
    TextPage textPage; // the activity that calls the AsyncTask
List<String> story = new ArrayList<String>();

GetTextInfoTask(TextPage textPage) {
    this.textPage = textPage;
}
    ... // your doInBackground function here

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object objR){
    // A toast is displayed in the TextPage Activity once the data is finished downloading
    Toast.makeText(textPage.getBaseContext(), story.get(0),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: This is what i want to do. story.add(line); How do I call onPostExecute and do this?

Comment: Keep  story.add(line); in the doInBackground function. What you want to add in the onPostExecute function is when the UI handles the display of the text in a view. onPostExecute automatically runs after the doInBackground function is done executing.